# Accessing User Defined Table type from another database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to access the  user defined table type from another database.

I have used the following format:

```
DECLARE @Hierarchy AS [DatabaseName].[Schema].[Table]
```

I get the following error:

> The type name '[DatabaseName].[Schema].[Table]' contains more than the
>   maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 1

How can I access the User Defined table type from another database?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SImple: You can not.

Schema definitions must be from the same database - and a user defined type in your usage scenario is a schema definition.

This is why there is only max. 1 prefix allowed - 1 prefix identifies another schema (within the same database).

So, you will have to copy the type definition over to your other database to use it.

Comment: And it's worth pointing out that even if you make that copy, there's still no way to e.g. create an instance in one database and pass it as a parameter to e.g. a stored procedure in the other database.

Answer (score -2):

You can access it in dynamic Sql statement

"USE [DatabaseName] DECLARE @Hierarchy"

Comment: Format your answer properly. Consider adding the code part of your answer in the code block