# Calling User Defined Table Type from a different db

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Assume I have this table type in dbA

```
USE dbA
GO

CREATE TYPE [dbo].Test AS TABLE(
    Col INT
)
GO

CREATE Procedure TestProc 
(
    @param [dbo].Test READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Blah'
END
```

Everything is good here and you can call stored procedure as

```
declare @udt dbo.Test
INSERT INTO @udt(Col) Values(1)
EXEC dbo.TestProc @param = @udt
```

I want to be able to call that same procedure from `dbB`. For that reason I created user dedfined type in dbB

```
USE dbB
GO

CREATE TYPE [dbo].Test AS TABLE(
    Col INT
)
GO
```

And now if I execute this:

```
USE dbB
GO

declare @udt dbo.Test
INSERT INTO @udt(Col) Values(1)

EXEC dbA.dbo.TestProc @param = @udt
```

I get this error:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure dbA.dbo.TestProc,
> Line 0 [Batch Start Line 11] Operand type clash: Test is incompatible
> with Test

How can I make that call to a procedure in dbA from dbB?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22854863/73226

Comment: @MartinSmith That isn't the same, I'm not trying to access user defined type from a different db, I already defined it in dbB

Comment: If I thought they were the same I would have already closed the question as duplicate. It does show why you aren't using the obvious approach though and indirectly that what you are trying is not possible. Per the comment on the accepted answer

Comment: UDTs don't support "duck typing" dbA.Test and dbB.Test are different types.  Period.  So this question is a dup.